# Has Spinoza been disproved by modern physics?

Tags: metaphysics, spinoza

As I understood it Spinoza claims everything has Extension, it occupies space.
But in physics there are things called point particles which are zero dimensional, they don't occupy space.

So for example photons do not have Extension therefore Spinoza is wrong, have I misunderstood something?

Thank you!

Comment: Not on this score. Photons are called point particles, but they are neither particles nor literally point-like, they are "quantum particles" whose wave functions extend over the entire universe. Not that it matters, Spinoza was well familiar with dimensionless geometric points, he modeled Ethics after Elements after all. Zero extension is still extension. It is much more mysterious how extension applies to God and abstractions, but to Spinoza somehow it does.

Comment: "In quantum mechanics, the concept of a point particle is complicated by the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, because even an elementary particle, with no internal structure, occupies a nonzero volume." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_particle Point-like refers to not having internal structure, rather than truly being located at a point

Answer (score -1):

First, point particles occupy space. The point particle at (1,1,1) in a 3D coordinate system occupies the space precisely at (1,1,1). Points are 0-dimensional, with a physical volume, surface area, and perimeter of 0. They, and any countable collection of them, have a measure of 0 under a standard measure but can have other measures under other choices.

Secondly, whether or not point particles exist in modern theories of physics is not entirely clear. It is true that, according to the wave/particle duality of quantum mechanics, Heisenberg’s Uncertainty Principle, and the fact that particles have a calculable de Brogle wavelength, particles seem to act as if they are not entirely point-like.

On the other hand, electrons, for example, have no internal structure and behave like point particles in other ways. Traditional interpretations of the collapse of the wave function conclude electrons are point particles after a measurement or observation. The details get hazy, dependent upon interpretation, and even philosophical very quickly. (Eg. For how long after? Decoherence anyone? How does this not violate the Uncertainty Principle and is the Uncertainty Principle epistemic or ontological?)

Nonetheless, modern theories of physics are so radically different from what anyone could have predicted before about 1870 (to be safe) that every philosopher who philosophized about physics was proven incorrect in countless foundational ways.

### Update in response to other posted answers

“Dimensionless point particles do not exist in physics” is false.

> After all, a particle, by its nature, is localized at a point, whereas the wave function (as it’s name suggests) is spread out in space (it’s a function of x, for any given time t). How can such an object represent the state of a particle? The answer is provided by Born’s **statistical interpretation** of the wave function, which says that [|psi| squared] gives the probability of finding a particle at point x at time t

– *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics*, Second Edition. David J. Griffiths.

> The electron (as far as we know) is a structureless point

– *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics*, Third Edition. David J. Griffiths. (This was published in 2018.)

This is a canonical standard-bearer for quantum mechanics. Many other places in the text explicitly refer to a particle as being a point (in the collapse of the wave function).

Comment: -1: The Griffiths quote isn't going into the ontology of the a particle point. A particle localised around a point means that it's extension is negligible and not that it's extension is zero. Ask what localised means in Math.SE.

Comment: I do not need to, I teach the subject. Griffiths is quite clear, and the mathematics is as well. But having philosophical outliers is common for us. “Extension” is not a mathematical or physical concept, but a philosophical one. I will not comment on it.

Comment: And I have studied maths and physics upto masters level at well respected institutions. Like I have already explained above, physical extension is usually understood as spatial. A particle localised around a point is one that has neglible spatial extension.

Comment: Moreover, a point, mathematically and physically speaking, indicates position.

Comment: The equation and interpretation Griffiths discusses would still be an excellent *approximation* for all current real-world experiments even in theories where the particle had non-zero extension near the Planck scale, like string theory. Also note that the book is about nonrelativistic quantum mechanics rather than relativistic quantum field theory (the latter incorporates special relativity but not general relativity, which would require a theory of quantum gravity), so that's already enough grounds for showing that the model he's discussing is only meant to be approximate rather than exact.

Comment: @Hypnosifl The statement under question is “Dimensionless point particles do not exist in physics”. This is false, and that is all I set out to show. Point particles are common in physics, as Griffiths demonstrates. Secondly, all physical theories that we’ve ever encountered are approximations. I am already quite modest in my answer, demonstrating the difficulties involved in interpretation.

Comment: I’m also not (and no one here) should be comfortable saying no modern theory has any point particles whosoever. There are a lot of exotic field theories and proposed TOEs that very few people are working on (sometimes just an individual). If the uncertainty principle is taken to be epistemic (not popular but not impossible) and traditional collapse is included, I would expect a serious relativistic theory to treat wave functions as collapsing to a point. Point being “point particles do not exist in physics” is too extreme and dogmatic.

Comment: OK, I interpreted "exist in physics" to mean "good evidence from physics that point particles actually exist", as opposed to "are included in models as useful approximations". By the latter standard, one could say that a Newtonian gravitational model that treats the sun, planets and/or moons as point particles would disprove the claim that "Dimensionless point particles do not exist in physics", but I doubt @MoziburUllah would consider that a counterexample since we know these bodies aren't actually point particles--probably he was using "exist in physics" to mean something diff. than you.

Comment: In Quantum Loop Gravity, we have geometric entities from which spacetime is woven that are Planck sized. In string theory, there is a kind of minimal length - this is T-duality. In Landau & Lifschitz *Classical Mechanics*, a point particle is defined as I have put it above. One aspect of the quantum revolution is that there are minimal scales, things do not reduce simply to nothing. The point I'm making is that point particles are philosophically incoherent.

Comment: Why collapse to a point and not collapse to a Planck volume? That seems much more reasonable to me.

Answer (score -2):

First, dimensionless point particles do not exist in physics. They are simply a way of speaking about a particle whose extension is negligible for the effects that are bring modelled.

Secondly, physics is generally geometric in myriad ways and hence about extension in myriad ways. This tallies with what Spinoza says about the physical world, it is a mode of extension. In fact, extension is simply a mode of the absolute substance, thought is another and there are infinitely many other unobservable modes.

Thus, Spinoza's theology is compatible with modern physics and hasn't been disproved by it.

Comment: are you nick land?

Answer (score -2):

One way he was proven wrong is the discovery of truly random behavior in quantum mechanics (edit: apparently it's not settled, see comments below). For Spinoza events necessary follow from their causes and are entirely determined by them.

Note that it does not have much consequence on his views, as our mind have no control over the results of quantic measurements, and our behavior is still determined by the laws of physics. In Ethics Spinoza states that dualists don't have the faintest idea of how a spaceless mind could affect our material body's behavior, and AFAIK it is still true to this day.

Photons don't occupy space but they are in space, they manifest their existence under the Extension attribute of Nature. When a photon goes from the Sun to our eye, both of those locations and the distance between them are part of the Extension. Of course, we can also have an idea of a photon and that's why they also exist under the Idea attribute (not sure of the correct English word, sorry), like everything else.

On the other hand, Antonio Samasio, who is not a physicist but a brain surgeon, wrote a very interesting book, *Looking for Spinoza: Joy, Sorrow, and the Feeling Brain*, where he explains how many intuitions of Spinoza about the human mind have been confirmed by modern neurology.

Comment: Whether quantum mechanics is truly random is unknown, both [Bohmian mechanics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qm-bohm/) and the various flavors of the [Everett interpretation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qm-everett/) (including the many-worlds interpretation) are fully deterministic [interpretations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics) of quantum mechanics, but all interpretations make identical predictions so they are untestable. It's possible a future theory of quantum gravity might settle the issue, though.

Comment: @hypnosifl thanks. I added a note in the answer. Anyway, as I say above wether its truly random or not does not radically change Spinozas system.